# How to get NSDate from string without converting it to UTC

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, swift2

I have following problem. Let's suppose that I receive from server some string containing date time in following format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxxx
```

This is a server date time and I would like to display it in application as it is. So if I receive date time:

```
2017-04-07T10:29:23+ 02:00
```

it means that on the server is `10:29:23 (08:29:23 UTC)`

and I would like to display it in application as:

```
04.07.2017 10:29:23
```

but whenever I try to convert the string to NSDate I get the date converted to UTC which is not desired because I lose information about server time zone. I use following code right now:

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601)
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxxx"

let date = formatter.dateFromString(dateString)
```

How can I achieve that in Swift (2.3)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is correct. If you `print` the date you'll get UTC. Try it in a playground. Two notes: `xxxx` can be replaced with `Z` and in the date string there must not be a space character between the plus/minus sign and the time zone value.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, I know that it will give me an UTC but as I wrote above I do not want this. I want to display server datetime as I've received that. So e.g. if on server is 10:00 (8:00 UTC), I'd like to display in the application also 10:00 (independently on application timezone).

Comment: If you want to ignore the time zone you have to strip the time zone information from the date string (for example with `replaceOccurrencesOfString` and `RegularExpression` option).

Comment: To be honest, I was taking it into consideration but I thought there might be some pretty solution for that. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so finally I've managed to resolve the problem using your hints.

Following code meets my expectations:

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601)
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxxx"

let timeZonePattern = "([+-]([01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9])$" // e.g. "+02:00"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
let dateStringWithoutTimeZone = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(dateString, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, dateString.characters.count), withTemplate: "Z")

let date = formatter.dateFromString(dateStringWithoutTimeZone)
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

`NSDate` does not have a built-in time zone. If you `print` an `NSDate` then it'll print in GMT because it has to print in *something*. But the date itself does not contain a time zone, and can't. They're time-zone independent.

To print a date in a particular time zone, configure an `NSDateFormatter` with the format and time zone that you want, then use `.stringFromDate`. Or don't set a time zone and it'll print in your device's time zone and locale, likely being what your user expects (e.g. your server says "event happened at 00:23+02:00" so to your CET user you'll display "event happened at 23:23", and to your EST user you display "event happened at 6:23PM").

Frustratingly, you have only one problem left: the date formatter understands the time zone in your original string (the +02:00), but can't communicate it to you by any means. So if you want to take an `NSDate` and print it in the same time zone as your server then you're going to have to determine the time zone on your own, communicate it via another channel, or hard-code it.